# No responed after pressing UICollectionViewCell in the UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, segue

when I come the part of sending image from UICollectionViewController to another ViewController  here is View A:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail Segue"])
     {
        PhotoDetailViewController *PhotoDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *path = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]  lastObject];

        Photo *selectedPhoto = self.photos[path.row];
        PhotoDetailVC.photo = selectedPhoto;
    }
}
```

and I receive it in the ViewController (View B) using:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.imageView.image= self.photo.image;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly? what is expected and didn't work?

Comment: when i pressed on the UICollectionViewCell there is no respones from the app and it should make segue to the View B @Mahmoud Adam

Comment: so where do you perform your segue? did you configured the delegate of the collection view? can you show your code inside `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: i perform my segue in the UIcollectionViewController (View A)
i don't use the 'collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:' method @Mahmoud Adam

Comment: can you edit the post and add this code as it might has the problem

Comment: @Mahmoud Adam is this better ?
jazak Allah kl kher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you didn't call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in any place in code which actually responsible for triggering navigation not `prepareForSegue:sender:` which is called when preparing for the navigation

so I suggest to implement `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` as the following

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Photo *selectedPhoto = self.photos[path.row];
    // this line is the one that is responsible for navigation
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail Segue" sender:selectedPhoto];
}
```

and modify `prepareForSegue:sender:` as the following

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail Segue"]) {
        PhotoDetailViewController *PhotoDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        PhotoDetailVC.photo = sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks 
it worked
but i'm beginner to iOS
could please , suggest me any resources ......?